# Proof of concurrency of transverse tangents and line joining centers of two disjoint circles

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

I read that "the transverse common tangents to two disjoint circles and the line joining the center of the circles are concurrent" and tried proving it.

[image: Geometry]

Can I get a hint to prove that lines **FI**, **GH** and **AC** are concurrent at E?

Comment: Title should better be "Proof of concurrency of  internal tangents and line joining centers of two disjoint circles"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the figure, we can prove that $A, C, B$ are collinear by showing that

$(1)$  $\alpha = \frac{\angle JCI}{2}= \frac{\angle HCK}{2}=\beta$,

and hence

$(2)$  $\angle ACH+ \angle HCB=180^o$

Comment: how  *∠ACH+∠HCB= $\pi$* if α = β ?

Comment: $\angle ACH + \angle HCB=\angle ACH+\beta=\angle ACH+\alpha$